# If value is 0 (zero) then increment it with max number +1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to UPDATE all new inserted values of 0 with the highest value from the same column + 1. Any value with zero should be updated by the highest value +1.  If the highest value is 30 below in the "Preference" column, then the next value should be 31 for Id 11 and 32 for Id 12.  New values are inserted every 30 seconds, could be multiple, from the source table that I have no access to into the table below (table 1).

The UPDATE statement is executed when a user drags and drops a row in the web app.

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[tbl1] SET
    Preference = @Preference
WHERE Id = Id
```

I need to somehow add that logic to this statement described above. This is where I am lost.

Any ideas?  Thank you for the help!!

For example:

| ID | Preference | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | 22 |
| 6 | 8 | 33 |
| 7 | 9 | 44 |
| 9 | 0 | 55 |
| 11 | 0 | 66 |

Required results:

| ID | Preference | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | 22 |
| 6 | 8 | 33 |
| 7 | 9 | 44 |
| 9 | 10 | 55 |
| 11 | 11 | 66 |

Comment: Hint, try `row_number`

Comment: This is my update statement after the drag and drop: UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[tbl1] SET Preference = @Preference WHERE Id = Id .  I need to somehow ad that logic to this statement described above.  This is where I am lost . . .

Comment: @lptr why do you keep providing answers in the comments? Why not just add as an answer?

Comment: @MonksDen start with building a query which gives you the new value, using `row_number` then convert it into an update.

Comment: Yes!  @lptr suggestion helped a lot.  Sorry for not knowing what to do here, I am kind of new to posting questions.

Comment: @lptr you do realise that comments get deleted eventually and then there will be no answer here?

Comment: Can you explain more on your statement `If the highest value is 30 below in the "Preference" column, then the next value should be 31 for Id 11 and 32 for Id 12`

Comment: Basically, each 0 value needs to be the next highest value.

Answer (score 0):

Gather the current maximum preference using a cross apply (or you could use a cross join) and together with row_number() ordered by ID you will increment preference as described:

```
with CTE as (
    select id, preference, cp.maxpref, row_number() over(order by id) rn
    from mytable
    cross apply (select max(preference) maxpref
                 from mytable p
                ) cp
    where preference = 0
    )
update cte
set preference = maxpref + rn
where preference = 0
```

see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3a7eb425b67c749c92dc87d2d5a726a3)*

```
 select *
 from mytable
 order by id
```

| ID | Preference | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7 | 22 |
| 6 | 8 | 33 |
| 7 | 9 | 44 |
| 9 | 10 | 55 |
| 11 | 11 | 66 |